# Variable path for file storage based on a user's group

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, storage

I am working on an application that allows users to upload files. I want to keep the uploaded files organized into pre-created folders named for the group that the user belongs to. I can't seem to find a way to make the path editable so that I can pass the group's name into the method as a parameter and have the file stored in that directory.

Here's my latest attempt that results in a "Failed to store file file] with root cause" exception.

```
@Service
public class StorageServiceImpl implements StorageService {

    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private Path path;

    public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file,String contentName, String groupName){
        //make so that files are stored in path/groupname
        this.path = Paths.get(this.path.toString() +"/"+groupName +"/");
        String filename = contentName+"-"+StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n"+filename + "\n\n\n");
        try {
            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file");
            }
            if (filename.contains("..")) {
                // This is a security check
                throw new StorageException(
                        "Cannot store file with relative path outside current directory "
                                + filename);
            }
            try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream()) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n"+this.path.resolve(filename) + "\n\n\n");
                Files.copy(inputStream, this.path.resolve(filename), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = String.format("Failed to store file %s", file.getName());
                throw new StorageException(msg, e);
            }
    }
}
```

Note: If the directory of the groupName is created before this method runs (as I intend to have it created when the group is created) then the method attempts to store the file in another directory of the same name inside that directory such as:

backend/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/TestGroup/TestGroup/test.jpg

See how TestGroup shows up twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using the absolutePath method from the private Path path to generate the string.

```
public void uploadFile(MultipartFile file,String contentName, String groupName){
        //make so that files are stored in path/groupname
        String filename = contentName+"-"+StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        File uploadFilePath = Paths.get(this.path.toAbsolutePath() + "/" + groupName+"/" + filename).toFile();
        try {
            if (file.isEmpty()) {
                throw new StorageException("Failed to store empty file");
            }
            if (filename.contains("..")) {
                // This is a security check
                throw new StorageException(
                        "Cannot store file with relative path outside current directory "
                                + filename);
            }
            try (InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(uploadFilePath);) {


                FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream,out);
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = String.format("Failed to store file %s", file.getName());
                throw new StorageException(msg, e);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, here you are trying to inject value to a varible of type Path.

```
@Value("${upload.path}")
private Path path;
```

how about reading the value to a String variable and storing it as a `File` and then using it to upload like below,

```
@Value("${upload.path}")
private String path;
```

And then using it

```
public void uploadFile( MultipartFile file, String contentName, String groupName )
{
    String filename = contentName + "-" + StringUtils.cleanPath( file.getOriginalFilename() );
    // use a File object here
    File uploadFilePath = Paths.get( new File( path ).getPath() + "/" + groupName + "/" + filename ).toFile();
    try
    {
        try( InputStream in = file.getInputStream(); OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( uploadFilePath ) )
        {
            // Leverage the support of Spring's FileCopyUtils Here
            FileCopyUtils.copy( in, out );
        }
        catch( IOException ex )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( ex );
        }
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        String msg = String.format( "Failed to store file %s", file.getName() );
        throw new StorageException( msg, e );
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted this method but instead of trying to store the file at the full path like C:/Desktop/WEB-INF/groupName it now takes the upload path string literally and only stores at /WEB-INF/groupName. In the old implementation "this.path.resolve(filename)" was responsible for producing the full absolute path. Is there a way to do that with this method too?

Comment: @Flypkey Then your approach is correct, only thing you need to do is use `path.toAbsolutePath()` instead of using a string as path. If my answer was helpful, please mark it as an accepted answer